# Custom template messed up when set to static home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a custom wordpress template that is working fine until it's not set to static home page. When I set my custom template as my homepage all the `div` gets messed up. all my content start appearing inside `footer`.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: school search
 * 
 * Display latest posts and categories
 * 
 * @package        OWT school search
 * @version        Release: 1.0
 * @since          available since Release 1.0
 */
?>

    <?php
        get_header(); ?>
        </header>   
            <div id="top" class="row" >
                <div id="search-box" class="col-xs-12">
                    <form class="form-inline" name="search" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="search-bar">Search School:</label>
                            <input name="search-bar" type="text" class="form-control" id="search-bar" placeholder="School Name or Street" list="datalist">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="state">State:</label>
                            <select name="state" class="form-control" id="state">
                                <option value="">Select State</option>
                                <option value="Uttar Pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
                                <option value="Haryana">Haryana</option>
                                <option value="Maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="city">City:</label>
                            <select name="city" class="form-control" id="city">
                                <option value="">Select City</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="area">Area:</label>
                            <select name="area" class="form-control" id="area">
                                <option value="">Select Area<option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
            $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM school_data, areas group by Name;" );
        ?>
        <datalist id="datalist">
            <?php
                foreach ( $result as $print )   {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $print->Name ; ?>">
            <option value="<?php echo $print->Address_1 ; ?>">
            <option value="<?php echo $print->City ; ?>">
            <option value="<?php echo $print->State ; ?>">
            <?php } ?>
        </datalist>
        <?php
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
                $searchBar = $_POST["search-bar"];
                $state = $_POST["state"];
                $city = $_POST["city"];
                $area = $_POST["area"];
                $state = $_POST["state"];
                if($searchBar == "" && $state == "" && $city == "" && $area == "" && $state == ""){
                    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='Msg'><strong>Error!</strong>Please fill at least one entry in the form above</div>";
                }
                else{
                    $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.State FROM school_data a, areas b WHERE (a.Name LIKE'%$searchBar%' OR a.Address_1 LIKE'%$searchBar%' OR a.City LIKE'%$searchBar%' OR b.State LIKE '%$searchBar%')";
                    $group_by = " group by a.Name";
                    if( $state == "" ){
                        $sql = $sql.$group_by;
                    }
                    else{
                        if( $city == "" ){
                            $sql = $sql." AND (b.State = '$state')".$group_by;
                        }
                        else{
                            if( $area == "" ){
                                $sql = $sql." AND (b.State = '$state' AND a.City = '$city')".$group_by;
                            }
                            else{
                                $sql = $sql." AND (b.State = '$state' AND a.City = '$city' AND a.Address_1 = '$area')".$group_by;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( $sql ); ?>
                    <div id="main-container">
                        <div id="resultArea" class="row">
                            <div id="results" class="col-md-3">
                                <?php $num = 1;
                                foreach ( $result as $print )   { ?>
                                    <div id="output">
                                        <strong id="output-name">
                                            <a href="javascript:geocodeAddress('<?php echo $print->Name; ?> ,<?php echo $print->City; ?>, <?php echo $print->State; ?>');"><?php echo $num; ?>. <?php echo $print->Name; ?></a>
                                        </strong><br/>
                                        <p><?php echo $print->Address_1; ?>, <?php echo $print->City; ?>, <?php echo $print->Pin; ?>, <?php echo $print->State; ?><hr></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php $num++; }  ?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="map" class="col-md-9">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

        <?php   }   
            }
            else{ ?>
                <div id="main-container">
                        <div id="resultArea" class="row">
                            <div id="results" class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="def-msg">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Type any address or school name in the first box, then click Search</li>
                                        <li>You can select a Borough and Grade to better focus your results</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="map" class="col-md-9">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php }

            ?>
        <script>
            jQuery("#state").change(function($) { 
                    var data = {
                                'action': 'my_action',
                                'selectedState': jQuery('#state').val()
                            };
                    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(cityResponse) {
                    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = cityResponse;
                    });
            });
            jQuery("#city").change(function($) { 
                var data = {
                            'action': 'my_action',
                            'selectedCity': jQuery('#city').val()
                            };
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = response;
                });
            });
            var map;
            function myMap() {
                var mapProp = {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629),
                        zoom: 5,
                    };
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
            }

            function geocodeAddress(address) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == "OK") {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                            });
                            marker.setMap(map);
                            if (results[0].geometry.viewport) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
                            else if (results[0].geometry.bounds) map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
                            else map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        } 
                        else alert("geocoder failed, status: "+status);
                })
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=2-_I4Dc0KSh3VI_OCaCDcG68oq8&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Now this code runs fine but whenever I add `<?php get_footer(); ?>` at the end al the content of my template gets inside the footer

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I've edited my question. please have a look

Comment: Can you post the footer and header code too? most probably there is scripts or css conflict

Comment: @MohammedSaquibSiddique, According to your question i have belief that your footer div are not closed well due to that you are getting problems